# How to create filters for a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am new to VueJS and web development in general. I am working on a project that displays my Vue components as cards. I was hoping to make this web app a SPA with only 1 card ever appearing at a time.

Is it possible to put something such as a search field where I can type (say a name or some text found within the card) and have that card appear. Sorry in advance if I'm unclear. Also is this the best way about creating multiple instances of this card? Thanks!

```
Vue.component('blog-card', {
   template: '#blog-card',
   data: function data() {
      return {
      name: 'LeBron James',
      category: 'Slasher',
      image: 'http://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp- 
      content/uploads/headshots/nba/latest/260x190/2544.png',
      author: '99',
      desc: '23 Badges'
  };
 }
});

Vue.component('blog-card2', {
  template: '#blog-card',
   data: function data() {
      return {
      name: 'Steph Curry',
      category: 'Shot Creator',
      image: 'http://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/headshots/nba/latest/260x190/201939.png',
      author: '96',
      desc: '15 Badges'
    };
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#container'
});
```

Comment: uses computed property then return something like `return this.cards.filter((item)=>{ /*check item if include the keyword, like this.keyword*/})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a vue component for a generic card with props (name, category, desc.. etc).
Then place the template in your main vue app and populate its props. That way you are not being redundant with the components.

```
Vue.component('blog', {
props:  [   name: String,
            category: String,
            image: String,
            age: Number
        ],
template: '<h3>{{ name }}</h3>
            <span>{{ category }}</span>
            <img v-bind:src="image">
            <span>{{ age }}</span>'})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you could either use props and i think that's easiest way of doing it, since looks like you are just changing data, but if you need to render differents components you can do it with a component directive, like this:

```
<component v-bind:is="currentComponent"></component>
```

so this way you can create a mini form called search or something like that and once it got submitted, you can updated the currentComponent prop and that will render the component to need to be rendered. This is actually on the documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html